# Stage of pipeline gets skipped even tho it doesnt have any conditions

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-yaml-pipelines

Guys
Im currently working on an azure devops yaml pipeline, and i have a weird problem.
For some reason on of my stages (marked in red) gets skipped, even tho it doesnt have any conditions definded.
[image: structure of yaml pipeline]
Heres the code of the stage and the previous stage:

Stage before the one that gets skipped:
[image: stage before]

Stage that gets skipped:
[image: Code of skipped]
Any Ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Post the actual text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour if you don't specify a condition is to only run if *all* previous steps/jobs/tasks in the dependency tree have succeeded. And since you have a task in the previous steps which is skipping, the following stage is not running.

I think you can add something like this:

```
dependsOn: Download_from_source
condition: succeeded('Download_from_source')
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is exactly what @James wrote, but to solve it you need to add the following condition (in the `Upload_to_Target` stage):

```
condition: and(not(failed()), not(canceled()))
```